# Spring boot Application in Cloud run returns IPV6 address

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-run

I have a spring boot application with rest controller apis which is deployed in cloud run.

The Request header returns ipv6 address instead of ipv4 .

Based on various stack overflow posts, the springboot application is started with the following options,

java -jar -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true xxx.jar

However, still req.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR") returns ipv6 address.

Any idea how to get ipv4 address from the application deployed in cloud run.

Regards

Srinivasan

Answer (score 0):

`req.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")` returns a http header, not an IP address. You get whatever the reverse proxy (that is forwarding the request) puts there. It could be a host name, or (as String) an IP address, either V4 or V6.

This header has *nothing at all* to do with the "prefer" options that you set: It's the browser that's initiating the connection. If the browser connected to the webserver via IPV6, the webserver will have no clue about the browser's IPV4 address - the webserver can only forward what it knows.

Answering your additional comment-question: You already have the browser's IP address. It happens to be IPV4 - and it's about time to be able to deal with it.

If you *really really really* are sure that you actively only want to support IPV4, you'll have to make sure that your DNS records only provide an IPV4 address for the domain at question. *Then* nobody will connect through IPV6.

Comment: ok, then how to get the ip address of the browser client then ?

Comment: I've edited that part into my answer. You already have their IP address. It just happens to be IPV6, because that's what's used.